# What is the definition of "irrational algebraic expression"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can somebody please tell what is the definition of "irrational algebraic expression"? Would this be analogous to the situation of irrational numbers?
What are some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An irrational algebraic expression is an algebraic expression ([Wikipedia: Algebraic expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_expression)) that contains a root sign or a power with broken rational exponent and is not a rational expression .

examples: $1-\sqrt{3}$, $1-3^{\frac{1}{2}}$

counterexamples: $1-\sqrt{4}$, $1-4^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Thanks for answering

Answer (score 2):

An algebraic number is a real number that is the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients. For instance, $\sqrt 2$ is a root of the polynomial $x^2-2$, so $\sqrt 2$ is an algebraic number. And $\sqrt[5]{\sqrt 3-1}$ is a root of the polynomial $(x^5+1)^2-3$, so it too is an algebraic number.

Not all algebraic numbers can be expressed as a combination of $n$th roots in this way $-$ in the jargon, not all polynomials are solvable by radicals. This is a key result of [Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory).

Note that all rational numbers are algebraic, because $\frac{p}{q}$ is a root of the polynomial $qx-p$.